# load Firefox without add-ons, extensions, or plug-ins

Tags: firefox, command-line, firefox-addon

Is there a command line switch available to load Firefox without add-ons, extensions, or plug-ins ?

I'm running Angular Karma tests from the command line and finding that if browsers loaded with extensions, add-ons, plug-ins do not start properly.

For Internet Explorer there is the `-extoff` switch.  Is similar available for Firefox ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either start in safe-mode or create a separate profile without extensions and specify that with one of the appropriate flags.

But if your tests break when extensions are present you may want to consider whether your code is brittle to extensions, i.e. might fail on a user's browser who also has the extensions in question installed.

```
$ firefox --help

Usage: /usr/lib/firefox-developer-edition/firefox [ options ... ] [URL]
       where options include:

[...]
  -P <profile>       Start with <profile>.
  --profile <path>   Start with profile at <path>.
[...]
  --safe-mode        Disables extensions and themes for this session.
```